# How should I start solving it in Scala rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

student marks are stored in hdfs://Hmaster/training/dump/stdmarks1.txt

Input format: sno, name, m1, m2, m3, branch
create an rdd and display the student names of students belongs to branch: cse
Display the names of students using println.
format of output:
xxxx
yyyy

And I have a sample text file

**1,RAMESH,70,52,60,CSE**

**2,SOMESH,80,69,88,ECE**

**3,VANITA,90,73,92,CSE**

**4,KIRAN,74,96,68,IT**

The output should be only student's name:

> RAMESH

> VANITA

Already uploaded the text file in hdfs as given but not able to do further steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example:

```
spark
 .read
 .option("header", "true")
 .csv(hdfsFilePath)
 .where(col("m3") === "CSE")
 .select("name")
 .distinct()
 .show()
```

I recommend you to read the [documentation.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html)